# Generating N random unit vectors with their sum equal to 0 (Python)

Tags: python, vector, random

I'd like to generate N random 3-dimensional vectors (uniformly) on the unit sphere but with the condition, that their sum is equal to 0. My attempt was to generate N/2 random unit vectors, while the other are just the same vectors with a minus sign. The problem is, as I'm trying to achieve as little correlation as possible, and my idea is obviously not ideal, since half of my vectors are perfectly anti-correlated with their corresponding pair.

Comment: The question you are asking will never result in a solution that has no correlation. If vectors can cancel each other out, which is what you want, then they are correlated as they are simply transforms of each other. So, there is no answer to your question.

Comment: If the sum is 0, doesn't that limit one vector? Can you generate n-1 random , then the last one is just the precise vector to cancel the others?

Comment: That is true, however I'm wondering is there any better way approaching this problem. As I said, I'm trying only to minimize the correlations. To put things in perspective, I'm trying to generate an initial state on which I'm acting then with Metropolis algorithm and checking the auto-correlation function of the vectors, but the condition that their sum is equal to 0 is respected throughout the algorithm. My approach gives poor results, and I'm wondering if there's any way I could improve them.

Comment: @K.Cl They must all lay on the unit sphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem does not really have a solution, but you can generate a set of vectors that are going to be slightly less visibly correlated than your original solution of negating them. To be precise, if you generate `N / 2` vectors and negate them, then rotate the negated vectors about their sum by any angle, you can guarantee that the sum will be zero and the correlation will be a more complicated rotation than a negative identity matrix.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

N = 10

v1 = np.random.normal(size=(N / 2, 3))
v1 /= np.linalg.norm(v1, axis=1, keepdims=True)

axis = v1.sum(0)
rot = Rotation.from_rotvec(np.random.uniform(2.0 * np.pi) * axis / np.linalg.norm(axis))

v2 = rot.apply(-v1)

result = np.concatenate((v1, v2), axis=0)
```

This assumes that `N` is even in all cases. The normal distribution is a fairly standard method to generate points uniformly on a sphere: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html.

If you had some leeway from the sum being exactly zero, you could align two random sets of `N / 2` vectors so that their sums point opposite each other.

Answer (score 0):

In this code, I tried to generate vectors selected from a sphere by converting a `theta, phi` to `x, y, z`.

[image: Cartesian System Coordinates]

```py
import numpy as np

def vectorize(theta, phi):
    x = np.cos(phi) * np.cos(theta)
    y = np.cos(phi) * np.sin(theta)
    z = np.sin(phi)
    return np.array([x, y, z])

theta_range = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.01)
phi_range = np.arange(-np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, 0.01)
TH, PI = np.meshgrid(theta_range, phi_range)
whole_map = np.vstack((TH.flatten(), PI.flatten())).T

# Number of vectors: 
N = 100

# Selecting N/2 Vectors first at random
v_selected = np.random.choice(range(whole_map.shape[0]), N // 2)

vectors = np.array([vectorize(whole_map[ind][0], whole_map[ind][1]) for ind in v_selected])

# Doubling up the number of vectors by adding the negate of each vector to the vector set
vectors = np.vstack((vectors, -vectors))


print(vectors.sum(axis=0))
# array([1.94289029e-16, 1.17961196e-16, 1.11022302e-16])
# Almost 0, but isn't zero because of floating number precision when converted to binary
```

Here is the scatter plot of the points generated on the sphere with `radius=1`:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but the problem is that the last vector sum_v isn't a unit vector. My condition is that all vectors must lay on the unit sphere.

Comment: @mb28025 Okay, I found a way. First we choose `n/2` vectors and then, for each vector, we are adding its opposite to have `n` vectors in total all of which are unit vectors.

Comment: Also, your distribution is heavily biased towards the poles

Comment: @aminrd. OP already stated this not to be a valid option